# Popup doesn't opens if the parameters are long

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an application in which a popup needs to open on button click, which contains three parameters.
Everything works if I only pass 1 parameter, but if I pass more parameters (they are long), then no popup opens.
What might be the problem here?

```
<?php
         $number = mt_rand(1,50000); //generate anti-csrf token
         $entry = base64_encode($number);
         $escape = sha1($number);
         ?>
           <a href="#" onclick="javascript:popUp(<?php echo $reviews->companyid; ?>,<?php echo $entry; ?>,<?php echo $escape; ?>);">Concur</a> |
```

Popup opener

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function popUp(id,entry,escape)
  {
    popupWindow = window.open('admin_browse_userprofile.php?id='+id+'&entry='+entry+'&escape='+escape,'User','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=650,height=550');
      popupWindow.focus();
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: What is the resulting Javascript that is generated from your PHP? Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: @RafaelDiaz
I have already gone through that link and nothing helped me.

Comment: @Adam
The resulting is :- `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:popUp(3,NDg2Mjc=,0403f58fa5b747dfe029ee749cd1c6471716eed0);">Concur</a>`

Comment: I'm not sure what triggered the -1. Stackoverflow should add a facility that when someone gives a -1, the reason must be provided as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only reason the first one works is because you have anumber and numbers do not need quotes.

It throws an error because you have strings that are not wrapped in quotes.

```
popUp(123,FOO,BAR);
```

should be

```
popUp(123,'FOO','BAR');
```

And if the text inside contains " and ' you need to handle those.

Comment: I changed my code to `javascript:popUp(<?php echo $reviews->companyid; ?>,'<?php echo $entry; ?>','<?php echo $escape; ?>');"` and it worked.
Thank you.